# How to prevent picked up object from changing its scale?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing an issue when I pick up an object in my game. Whenever I pick up an object and look around while holding the object, it stretches based on the perspective. Here is an example of an object before and after picking up:

Before picking up:

[image: Here is the original item size]

After picking up:
[image: Here is how it becomes after]

How can I maintain the object's scale and prevent it from stretching?

```
    public void PickupObject()
    {
    physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
    currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
    pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   /* priorConstraints = pickupRB.constraints;    // <--- NEW
    pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;    // <--- NEW*/
    pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
     pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
     pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;
    //   pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
    //  StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp());
}
```

The following code snippet is in `Update()` :

```
if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
        {
            
            HoldingItemIcon.SetActive(true);
            InteractIcon.SetActive(false);
            CenterIcon.SetActive(false); 
            currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
            currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
            currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
            // pickupRB.transform.SetParent(PickupParent.transform);
            Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
            pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
            Vector3 camerDirection = mainCamera.transform.forward;
            // Throw object
            if (Throw)
            {
                HoldingItemIcon.SetActive(false);
                InteractIcon.SetActive(false);
                pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
                pickupRB.isKinematic = false;
                pickupRB.AddForce(camerDirection * 500);
                currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
                pickupRB.transform.parent = null;               
            }
            Throw = false;

        }

 public void BreakConnection()
        {
          pickupRB.isKinematic = false; 
          pickupRB.transform.parent = null;
          pickupRB.constraints = priorConstraints;
          //   pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
          currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
          lookObject = null;
          physicsObject.pickedUp = false;
          currentDist = 0;
          pickupRB.useGravity = true;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

pickupParent's lossy scale while an object is picked:

[image]

Comment: PickupParent probably has a lossyScale other than **1**, and if you set it as parent, it will change the scale of your picked up object. PickupParent should invert the lossyScale of its parent (assuming it has no mesh), such that it has unit lossyScale.

Comment: it is scaled 1. I added a screenshot of the inspector. please have a look.

Comment: That does not mean much, you need to make the lossyScale 1, what you show in the screen shot is the local scale. If you `Debug.Log(PickUpParent.lossyScale)`it should be `Vector3.one`. Since your player changes scale whenever they crouch, this should be done on a per-frame basis.

Comment: alright, check my question again, please. I added this debug line and captured the result

Comment: while the picked up object is stretched, can you log the lossy scale of that? it is imho impossible that it is 1 and stretched

Comment: what I showed is the lossy scale of the pickupParent in Start(). I print the same line when the object is being picked up and send you the result.

Comment: So I tried to print debug the lossyScale when the object is picked. what I got is whenever I'm pointing stight the lossyScale is all 1. but whenever I look up or down while holding an item, the lossy scale changes a little (as shown in the image above).

Comment: So, any idea how ti fix this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245773/discussion-between-one-full-time-equivalent-and-okashi).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have an empty gameObject as a child of your player. That object is going to be the pickableObjectsParent and give this parent object the scale values of 1/(player's scale).

Comment: currently, I have the empty gameObject as a child of the player. it is called PickupParent in my case. but I don't understand how exactly to make it have the same scale as the objects ?

Comment: Sorry I think what you should do is have the object's parent's scale  = 1/player's scale

Comment: it is currently 1. you can see I added a screenshot

Comment: And what is the player's scale?

Comment: I edited the question and added the player inspector

Comment: put the parent object's scale on the Y axis to 1.25 and keep the other axis to 1 because 1.25=1/.8

Comment: unfortunately, still does not work. it still changes the scale every time it's picked up and dropped.